# How to find the $\textbf{S}$ in $\textbf{SQS}^\text{T}$ in order to apply Sylvester's Law of Inertia?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

I'm trying to use Sylvester's Law of Inertia to find the the values of $k$ that make 
$$(k+4)x^2_1+2kx_1x_2+2x_2^2$$ 
a semi-definite positive form. Assuming $\textbf{Q}$ is the coefficients matrix of the quadratic form, I don't know any methodical procedure to find the $\textbf{S}$ that diagonalizes $\textbf{Q}$ through $\textbf{SQS}^\text{T}$.

---

I've read the whole Wikipedia article, I looked for it in different forums, YouTube and Google, and still haven't got a clue about how to procede, yet I have the feeling it must be quite simple.

If you don't want to give me a full explanation, you can of course link me to a a comprehensive explanation somewhere else. But, really, I searched for hours and nothing seems satisfying. Is it a matter of simple intuition?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, you're in $\Bbb R^2$, so it's not hard.

1. Write down the matrix $Q$:
   $$
   Q = \pmatrix{k+4 & k \\ k & 2}.
   $$
2. Find its eigenvalues. 
   $$
   p(x) = \det(Q - xI) = \det \pmatrix{k+4-x & k \\ k & 2-x} =
   (k+4 - x) (2-x) - k^2. 
   $$
3. Write this out as a quadratic in $x$, and compute the two eigenvalues using the quadratic formula. (You'll have to do this yourself. But I'll do it for $k = 0$, for instance. In that case, $p(x) = (4-x)(2-x) = x^2 - 6x + 8$, so the roots are
   $$
   x_{1,2} = \frac{6 \pm \sqrt{36 - 32}}{2} = 
   \frac{6 \pm 2}{2} = 4, 2
   $$

   4. For each eigenvalue, find the corresponding eigenvector, i.e., solve 
      $$
      (Q - x_1 I) \pmatrix{u\\v} = \pmatrix{0\\0}
      $$
      to find the eigenvector. Then normalize it (i.e., divide it by its length) and call those vectors $v_{1,2}$
4. Put the two eigenvectors into a matrix as its columns; that matrix is the $S$ that you want. (Or maybe you need to use the rows..do it and try both!)

Comment: Does this apply to any quadratic form, no matter how many variables it includes?

Comment: John, for when the eigenvalues are intractable, and all that is necessary for using Sylvester Inertia:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: I put an example as an answer, symmetric $H$ that is 4 by 4

Comment: The general method applies, but for more than two variables, finding the exact eigenvalues may be intractable, so it's not the method to use. As @WillJagy points out, there's a more general method that doesn't need the eigenvalues, but in a 2 x 2 case, my approach might be just as easy (or easier).

Answer (score 1):

here is one with very unpleasant eigenvalues. We don't bother with them.

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 11 & 4 & 3 \\ 
11 & 12 & 4 & 7 \\ 
4 & 4 & 7 & 12 \\ 
3 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 11 & 4 & 3 \\ 
11 & 12 & 4 & 7 \\ 
4 & 4 & 7 & 12 \\ 
3 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  \\ 
4 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 7 & 12 \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  & 12 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 5 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 2 }  \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 21 }{ 2 }  & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 5 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 21 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 127 }{ 8 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  & 0 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 143 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 228 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 228 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 127 }{ 8 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 41 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 143 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 228 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 228 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 463 }{ 25 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 271 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 241 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 143 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 569 }{ 143 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 271 }{ 143 }  &  \frac{ 241 }{ 143 }  &  -  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 11 & 4 & 3 \\ 
11 & 12 & 4 & 7 \\ 
4 & 4 & 7 & 12 \\ 
3 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 271 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 241 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 143 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 569 }{ 143 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  &  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 25 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 143 }{ 25 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 569 }{ 143 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 12 }{ 25 }  &  -  \frac{ 23 }{ 25 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 228 }{ 143 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
8 & 11 & 4 & 3 \\ 
11 & 12 & 4 & 7 \\ 
4 & 4 & 7 & 12 \\ 
3 & 7 & 12 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$